# Removing the only (last) keyboard layout for the language in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

Is it possible to remove the only keyboard layout for the non primary language in Windows 10 (Version 21H2, build 10.0.19044.2965)?

For example, I have Portuguese language installed as I am learning it and having some user interface in Portuguese helps me to learn new words. But having a Portuguese keyboard annoys me as a have other 2 keyboards, one of them is latin-based and covers all my needs in entering Portuguese texts.

If I go to the `Start -> Settings -> Time -> Language -> Portuguese (Portugal) -> Options`, click on Portuguese in keyboard list, the Remove button is grayed out and cannot be clicked. Are there any tools to remove keyboard layouts from the command line?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot.  This will let us understand which language packs you have installed and what each support (by their icons). More importantly is an English translation of the output of the command `Get-WinUserLanguageList`